# Euler method (explicit and implicit)

Tags: python, math, numeric, numerical-methods

I'd like to implement Euler's method (the explicit and the implicit one)
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for the following model:

```
x(t)' = q(x_M -x(t))x(t)
x(0) = x_0
```

where q, x_M and x_0 are real numbers.

I know already the (theoretical) implementation of the method. But I couldn't figure out where I can insert / change the model.
Could anybody help?

EDIT: You were right. I didn't understand correctly the method. Now, after a few hours, I think that I really got it! With the explicit method, I'm pretty sure (nevertheless: could anybody please have a look at my code? )

With the implicit implementation, I'm not very sure if it's correct. Could please anyone have a look at the implementation of the implicit method and give me a feedback what's correct / not good?

```
def explizit_euler():
    ''' x(t)' = q(xM -x(t))x(t)
    x(0) = x0'''
    q = 2. 
    xM = 2
    x0 = 0.5 
    T = 5 
    dt = 0.01 
    N = T / dt 
    x = x0
    t = 0.
    for i in range (0 , int(N)):
        t = t + dt
        x = x + dt * (q * (xM - x) * x)
        print '%6.3f %6.3f' % (t, x)



def implizit_euler():
    ''' x(t)' = q(xM -x(t))x(t)
    x(0) = x0'''
    q = 2.
    xM = 2
    x0 = 0.5
    T = 5
    dt = 0.01
    N = T / dt
    x = x0
    t = 0.
    for i in range (0 , int(N)):
        t = t + dt
        x = (1.0 / (1.0 - q *(xM + x) * x))
        print '%6.3f %6.3f' % (t, x)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is wrong with the code you show, other than the bad indentation? What do you mean by "insert / change the model"?

Comment: So what's unclear to you? Your code even have a line with an explicit comment `# Righthand side of differential equation`. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: @SergGr Yeah, but what do I have to insert there? return q*(x-dt)*dt ?

Comment: @DMan, what makes you think `dt` should be a part of the "model" at all? Do you really understand how the Euler method works (theoretically)?

Comment: @SergGr Yeah in theory, yes. But as you can see, I've a specific model - where / how do I have to change the code above in order to consider "my" model and the indicated equation?

Comment: @DMan, sorry I don't think that you really understand the Euler method in theory. That code is a quite straightforward implementation of it. I think you should try to re-read the description of the method and try to use it manually. Then it will be quite easy to understand where and how to change this code.

Comment: @SergGr You were right...I didn't understand well the method and it took my a few hours. But now, I think I got it. Please see my updated and edited question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you've probably got the right idea for the explicit euler (I've not tested it), but for implicit euler you need some more theory. If `x_prime = F(x, t)` then you're trying to find `x_{n+1}` such that `x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \Delta t F(x_{n+1}, t_{n+1})`, which typically requires some sort of solver.

Answer (score 3):

**Pre-emptive note**: Although the general idea should be correct, I did all the algebra in place in the editor box so there might be mistakes there. Please, check it yourself before using for anything really important.

I'm not sure how you come to the "implicit" formula

```
        x = (1.0 / (1.0 - q *(xM + x) * x))
```

but this is wrong and you can check it by comparing your "explicit" and "implicit" results: they should ***slightly*** diverge but with this formula they will diverge drastically.

To understand the implicit Euler method, you should first get the ***idea*** behind the explicit one. And the idea is really simple and is explained at the [Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Derivation) section in the wiki: since derivative `y'(x)` is a limit of `(y(x+h) - y(x))/h`, you can approximate `y(x+h)` as `y(x) + h*y'(x)` for small `h`, assuming our original differential equation is

```
    y'(x) = F(x, y(x))
```

Note that the reason this is only an approximation rather than exact value is that even over small range `[x, x+h]` the derivative `y'(x)` changes slightly. It means that if you want to get a better approximation of `y(x+h)`, you need a better approximation of "average" derivative `y'(x)` over the range `[x, x+h]`. Let's call that approximation just `y'`. One idea of such improvement is to find both `y'` and `y(x+h)` at the same time by saying that we want to find such `y'` and `y(x+h)` that `y'` would be actually `y'(x+h)` (i.e. the derivative at the end). This results in the following system of equations:

```
    y'(x+h) = F(x+h, y(x+h))
    y(x+h) = y(x) + h*y'(x+h)
```

which is equivalent to a single "implicit" equation:

```
    y(x+h) - y(x) = h * F(x+h, y(x+h))
```

It is called "implicit" because here the target `y(x+h)` is also a part of `F`. And note that quite similar equation is mentioned in the [Modifications and extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method#Modifications_and_extensions) section of the wiki article.

So now going to your case that equation becomes

```
    x(t+dt) - x(t) = dt*q*(xM -x(t+dt))*x(t+dt)
```

or equivalently

```
    dt*q*x(t+dt)^2 + (1 - dt*q*xM)*x(t+dt) - x(t) = 0
```

This is a quadratic equation with two solutions:

```
    x(t+dt) = [(dt*q*xM - 1) ± sqrt((dt*q*xM - 1)^2 + 4*dt*q*x(t))]/(2*dt*q)
```

Obviously we want the solution that is "close" to the `x(t)` which is the `+` solution. So the code should be something like:

```
    b = (q * xM * dt - 1)

    x(t+h) = (b + (b ** 2 + 4 * q * x(t) * dt) ** 0.5) / 2 / q / dt
```

---

(*editor note:*) Applying the binomial complement, this formula has the numerically more stable form for small `dt`, where then `b < 0`,

```
    x(t+h) = (2 * x(t)) / ((b ** 2 + 4 * q * x(t) * dt) ** 0.5 - b)
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for all the explanations! I've still 1 question left: With python, is it also possible to compute the exact result in order to calculate the range of error? Because using Euler, we just approximate.

Comment: @DMan, if you can (mathematically) solve the original differential equation - you can implement the target function in Python as well. If you can't - Python is not a magic trick that does impossible. Actually the whole idea of the Euler method and other similar methods is to solve numerically differential equations that people don't know how to solve in general. So most probably you use it because you don't know the correct answer. Also some known theoretical error bounds are also mentioned in the wiki article.

Comment: @DMan You can calculate the exact solution with a bit of calculus. As a hint `1/(x*(x-x_m)) =  1/(x_m*(x - x_m)) - 1/(x_m*x)`. Alternatively, [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) should be able to handle it.

Comment: @Steve, good point. Still I think my general point stands: if you can solve the equation, you typically don't need to use Euler method at all.

Comment: @SergGr I completely agree, but as a learning tool it is constructive to test numerical methods on problems with known solutions.

Comment: @SergGr A fringe case, I've had a PDE which had an analytic solution, but it takes the form of an infinite sum which doesn't converge - in that case, despite having the actual solution, I still required a numerical method. Doesn't mean anything to either of our statements, but I found it interesting.